# Finding an angle in a figure with a regular octagon and regular pentagon

Tags: geometry

I've recreated the diagram using Adobe Illustrator.

> [image]
>
> The pink polygon is a regular octagon and the grey is a regular pentagon.

I've tried to solve this for a while now but get nowhere. It seems like all I do is create more random angles that don't contribute to the solution. I've tried extending lines but that doesn't seem to help me at all.

Most other problems I've been given are relatively easy.

Comment: Unfortunately, your diagram contains more confusion than information: if octagon and pentagon are regular with equal side length, the angle you marked with "67" is uniquely determined, already, and obviously not 67° (your diagram isn't very precise, but the error can't be that big)..

Comment: Do you have an answer booklet?

Comment: Yes. I do. The answer to this question is $58°$ @MohammadZuhairKhan

Comment: The sum of the interior angles of a polygon is always $(n-2)*180$.  You can use this to solve.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: Using GeoGebra, I find that, if the polygons actually share a side (as they *seem* to in the figure), then the angle marked $67^\circ$ is actually $42.07^\circ$, and $x$ is $33.07^\circ$. Something's amiss with the problem as described.

Comment: @Callus Yes, I've tried that, many times. All I do is find the angle sizes of the polygon.

Comment: I am not good at drawing here, so I'll try to handwave a bit.  Look at the left pink polygon.  8 corners.  $3$ are interior of a regular octogan, $2$ are exterior of regular pentagon.  One is the difference between interior of regular octagon and regular pentagon.  One is $67$.  The last one is the one you're looking for.

Comment: @Blue My book is extremely inaccurate with it's diagrams. The diagrams are really just there to clarify the problem. The numbers are what matters.

Comment: @Kalazakan: Inaccurate diagrams are fine. However, there doesn't seem to be enough information to solve the problem. The polygons *cannot* exactly share a side, because the $67^\circ$ measurement would be wrong. But, then, it's not clear how the polygons are arranged. Are the bottom edges even collinear? Do they share a midpoint, or do they share an endpoint (which one?)? Are they even parallel? Since we cannot trust the diagram, we need an accurate description.

Comment: Though the question is interesting, I voted to close because of the incoherence in the statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $y$ be the given angle (supposedly $67$, though it can't really be).

The vertex angle of a regular pentagon is $180-360/5 = 108$.
The vertex angle of a regular octagon is $180-360/8 = 135$.

The irregular pink pentagon on the right then has five angles which are clockwise from the top:
 $x$, $135$, $135$, $135-108$, $360-108-y$.

The sum of the angles of a pentagon is $(5-2)*180 = 540$. Therefore we get that 
$x+135+135+135-108+360-108-y = 540$, or $x=y-9$.

If $y$ really were 67, then $x$ would indeed be $58$, but those numbers do not match the reality of the drawing. Those angles could be right if the regular pentagon had a smaller edge length, but still shared its bottom-right vertex with the octagon.

Comment: Yes. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the common sides to be unit and setting the origin at the bottom left vertex, the angle $x$ is determined by its apex at $(0,1+\sqrt2)$ and the points $(1/\sqrt2,1+1/\sqrt2)$ and $(\cos2\pi/5,\sin2\pi/5)$.

The tangent of $x$ is given by the ratio of the cross-product of the two legs over their dot product.

$$x=\arctan\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}4-1-\sqrt2\right)+\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac{\sqrt5-1}4}{\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac{\sqrt5-1}4-\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}4-1-\sqrt2\right)}.$$

Comment: Typos not to be excluded !

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The sum of the internal angles of a convex polygon with $n$ sides (the angles between two consecutive sides) is equal to $\; (n-2)\pi$ (in radians).

Comment: This is of little use. The angle $x$ is a function of the relative positions of the two polygons, not just the directions of the sides.

Comment: It seems the pentagon is built from one side of the hexagon, so what's the ‘relative position’ in this case?

Comment: There is a shift between the centers.

Comment: I know they're different, but they're on a common symmetry axis for both polygons.

Comment: You don't understand the argument. You can translate the polygons freely, without changing the directions of the sides, and obtain any $x$. So the relative positions must appear explicitly.

Comment: I don't get it. Once you have the octagon, you choose  one of its sides and construct a regular pentagon from this side, inside the octagon. As to the vertices on the polygons joined by a straight line, there's no choice either.  So what can be moved which would change $x$?

Comment: Last attempt: move the pentagon by 0.73 units left and 2.32 unit right. If you just rely on angles, you'll get the same $x$, which is wrong.

Comment: But as I see the problem, once you' chose a side of the octagon, you can't move whatever, since this side is also a side of the pentagon, and everything is pre-determined. I  rely on nothing but this construction (and I don't even know whether the value given is consistent). Maybe my interpretation of the problem is wrong…

Comment: No worries, you don't get my point. But the original question is flawed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can not be solved: the inner corners of a regular pentagon are $108°$. Draw a straigth line connecting the right points of the upper and lower edges of the regular octagon. This gives a triangle. The lower corner is $108° - 90° = 18°$. The corner formed by the inner corner of the regular pentagon and the $67°$ forms a total of $108° + 67° = 175°$ and the corners of a triangle only have a total sum of $180°$... (i.e. the problem is not well written).